# why need to turn tensor into a list in tensorflow run.session()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am quite a newbie to tensorflow, but I just can't simply let go of my concern. Could anyone provide some explanation to help me understand why we need to turn the tensor into a list in session.run(fetches, feed_dict) in the following code? The code is from [Andrew Ng's Convolutional Neural Networks Week 2 Residual Networks](https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Residual%20Networks%20-%20v1.ipynb)(In [2] and [3]). In the line  `out = test.run([A], feed_dict={A_prev: X, K.learning_phase(): 0})`, why do we need to add [] to A?  Type(A) is class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor' and type([A]) is class 'list'. Thank you very much.

```
def identity_block(X, f, filters, stage, block):
    """
    Implementation of the identity block as defined in Figure 4

    Arguments:
    X -- input tensor of shape (m, n_H_prev, n_W_prev, n_C_prev)
    f -- integer, specifying the shape of the middle CONV's window for the main path
    filters -- python list of integers, defining the number of filters in the CONV layers of the main path
    stage -- integer, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network
    block -- string/character, used to name the layers, depending on their position in the network

    Returns:
    X -- output of the identity block, tensor of shape (n_H, n_W, n_C)
    """

    # defining name basis
    conv_name_base = 'res' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
    bn_name_base = 'bn' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'

    # Retrieve Filters
    F1, F2, F3 = filters

    # Save the input value. You'll need this later to add back to the main path. 
    X_shortcut = X

    # First component of main path
    X = Conv2D(filters = F1, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2a', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2a')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    ### START CODE HERE ###

    # Second component of main path (≈3 lines)
    X = Conv2D(filters = F2, kernel_size = (f, f), strides = (1,1), padding = 'same', name = conv_name_base + '2b', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2b')(X)
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    # Third component of main path (≈2 lines)
    X = Conv2D(filters = F3, kernel_size = (1, 1), strides = (1,1), padding = 'valid', name = conv_name_base + '2c', kernel_initializer = glorot_uniform(seed=0))(X)
    X = BatchNormalization(axis = 3, name = bn_name_base + '2c')(X)

    # Final step: Add shortcut value to main path, and pass it through a RELU activation (≈2 lines)
    X = Add()([X_shortcut, X])
    X = Activation('relu')(X)

    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return X

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as test:
    np.random.seed(1)
    A_prev = tf.placeholder("float", [3, 4, 4, 6])
    X = np.random.randn(3, 4, 4, 6)
    A = identity_block(A_prev, f = 2, filters = [2, 4, 6], stage = 1, block = 'a')
    print(type(A))
    print(type([A]))
    test.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out = test.run([A], feed_dict={A_prev: X, K.learning_phase(): 0})
    print("out = " + str(out[0][1][1][0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way tensorflow works.

When you say

```
out = test.run([A], feed_dict={A_prev: X, K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

you're essentially saying run the computation associated with `A`, and assign the result to `out`

---

Why a list? Tensorflow allows you to run lots of computations and reuse parts of the graph that might be related. For example, lets say you have all of the code you pasted and another function which depends on `A`

```
def double_input(input_tensor):
    return tf.math.add(input_tensor, input_tensor)

A_double = double_input(A)
```

and you then do

```
out, out_double = test.run([A, A_double], feed_dict={A_prev: X, K.learning_phase(): 0})
```

1) this allows it to run related computations in one pass

2) you're assigning the results of the two graph operations to two separate variables

---

I'm not at my personal machine and haven't been able to verify that the thing I've pasted above will actually run, but I hope it illustrates the idea at the very least

Comment: Hi lan, your quick and detailed explanations definitely helped a lot. But why it is necessary to turn the input into a list when there is only one input. However, in  another simple code below, it is not necessary to be turned into a list and it still works well?

Comment: The output difference between with and without [] in the code `out = test.run([A], feed_dict={A_prev: X, K.learning_phase(): 0}` is  that the out of test.run(A,..) is only a part of test.run([A],..).

Comment: It's not necessary as you've discovered when you've got just one input. As for the rest of your questions, I highly recommend just looking at the tensorflow documentation. [Session.run doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session#run)

> fetches: A single graph element, a list of graph elements, or a dictionary whose values are graph elements or lists of graph elements (described above).

Comment: @AlbertGLieu if my answer above helped answer your question consider accepting it